# Add class name to a newly created div and modify style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get a div by id, and adding an event listener to that div, in my case i am trying to implement a simple `mouseover` event. I am trying to create a new div element and in that element add a new class called `vehicles`, after adding className vehicles i am trying to modify the style attribute of width to 100px, the code provided is only for practice purposes even if it does not make sense in real life.

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementById("div-1");
myDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.classList.add('vehicles');
  const vehicles = document.getElementsByClassName("vehicles")[0];
  vehicles.setAttribute("style", "width: 100px");
});
```

```css
#div-1 {
  background-color: red;
  color: yellow;
  width: 20px;
}

.vehicles {
border: solid 2px black;
background-color: blue;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div-1">
    <p>This is a test</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you use jQuery, maybe you want to check this out: [add element to HTML using jQuery](https://codesearchable.com/ja/1541431/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append the new created elements and then it will work:

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementById("div-1");
myDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.classList.add('vehicles');
myDiv.append(newDiv); // append the new created div
  const vehicles = document.getElementsByClassName("vehicles")[0];
  vehicles.setAttribute("style", "width: 100px");
});
```

```css
#div-1 {
  background-color: red;
  color: yellow;
  width: 20px;
}

.vehicles {
border: solid 2px black;
background-color: blue;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
  <p>This is a test</p>
</div>
```

---

EDIT (comments):

```js
const myDiv = document.querySelector("#div-1"); // use the modern way to select element(s)
myDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) { // this is your original code
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div"); // this is also your original code
  newDiv.setAttribute("style", "width: 100px; background: black; height: 1em;"); // instead of adding class and manipulate it you can set the desired property via inline style
  myDiv.append(newDiv); // append the new created div 
});
```

```css
#div-1 {
  background-color: red;
  color: yellow;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-1">
  <p>This is a test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @GreyChanel thank you for your reply - please take a look on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Comment: But how can I add some style to the newDiv that is created, let say that I want to add a different color for each new vehicle that I create, is it any way of using this to access that particular element?

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori when you pointing to the [0] element you change the first time the new element append. After that it return to the initial css declaration. So either iterate all `.vehicles` or just change your css (:

Comment: I am trying to do this through JS, I can keep track of the element added and then use something like this [i] but i don't think that is efficient.

Comment: @SachihiroTakamori check my edit, this is one way you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You have just created a new element. You must add this element to the DOM tree.

For example,

```
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```